# How can I create a Python wheel for a specific set of python versions? py2.py3-none-any.whl is too broad

Tags: python, pip, distutils, pypi

I have a package that works on Python 2.4-2.7. 3.2-3.7. 
Note this is not for all of Python 2 or Python 3 but specific versions.

It also happens that this package supports Python 2.4 and 2.5 with different source code.

I had been distributing eggs for each version because that is very specific and I `setup.py bdist_wheel` was creating something too broad that would match Python versions I don't want to match on.

When I had created a wheel I would the extension `py2.py3-non-any.whl` which is wrong for Python 2.4 and 2.5. (And so is the tarball).

PyPi will allow only one tarball so right now I use the non 2.4, 2.5 source. It would be nice to be able to include the 2.4 2.5 source as well. Hmm, maybe I can do that as a zip? (Probably not).

How do I inform setup.py that I want just a `py35-non-any.whl`? Or py2 specified for 2.6 or 2.7? And py3 for just 3.2 and greater.

Or more generally what is an easy way to set things up so that pip will pick the right pypi file no matter what python version one is running?

Comment: Why are you even trying to support 13-year-old Python versions in the first place?

Comment: Why not? The goal of the code is to handle Python bytecode any version. Therefore it is also convenient to have the code run on any version. By the way, in the Python community when there is something that is hard to do or Python doesn't support well or its tooling and thinking lacking, that rather than admit it is hard or Python or its tools or thinking is deficient is to instead say, "You shouldn't  want to do that".

Comment: Because when a question is really hard it's pointless to ask it at SO. Instead you should find a solution yourself, publish your code at GH and describe the solution in a blog post.

Comment: Funny, while I was out biking an idea did occur to me that I'm working on. Stay tuned. However, I think you are very wrong about posting to SO. I don't think I you can truly know if is hard until you ask. It's possible it's been worked out before and I don't know it. Also, I don't believe SO is just for things that you can easily look up and just needs explaining it better. I believe it should also be for describing new and different kinds of problems, even if they are tough. I'm not sure I would describe this exactly as tough. Possibly just that things haven't been thought out that well.

Comment: Something else amusing: phd's comment is along the lines of jwodder's comment except instead of applied to Python and its tools, it is applied to SO. I think it funny that both people tend to answer Python questions a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `setup.py bdist_wheel` and it creates something too general, here is something simple minded one can do: just rename the file.

I tried this on a distribution in Pypi and it works: the wheel is preferred over the tarball and it pulls down the wheel for that version. 
Running the program subsequently works.

In my specific case, `setup.py bdist_wheel` created `foo-1.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl` but that was wrong because don't want all versions of Python 2 and Python 3 but some very specific versions.

But, for example, if I want this to adjust to only work on Python 2.7 and Python 3.6, I rename/copy to:

```
foo-1.2.3-py27-none-any.whl
foo-1.2.3-py36-none-any.whl
```

There may be other thoughts and ideas on how to accomplish, so I leave this open. If this indeed is the simplest thing to do, it might be nice if there were an option inside setup.py or whatever it is that handles `bdist_wheel` so that it would do the rename for you.

Are ranges allowed in the naming convention so that one can specify say 3.5-3.7 ? Or can one somehow give a list like `py25.py26.py27` ?

Comment: This is defined in pep 425 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/#compressed-tag-sets, where it says "each tag in a filename can instead be a '.'-separated, sorted, set of tags". That means "py25.py26.py27" should be valid. I haven't tested it, though.